# Ratio_to_report with round function

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate % contribution of each value in my data and also need a total to it with % to be limited to 2 decimal points.

Below is the code i have built:

```
SELECT test , count(*)as Total , floor(ratio_to_report(Total)over () as Percentage)     
FROM [abc_table]  
where platform in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
group by  test 
order by Percentage desc
```

I am getting the results if i remove floor, i.e. total and percentage but cannot limit the % to 2 decimal points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you still using Legacy SQL - you can use below to address your issue

```
#legacySQL
SELECT test, Total, ROUND(Percentage, 2) AS Percentage
FROM (
  SELECT test, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    RATIO_TO_REPORT(Total) OVER() AS Percentage
  FROM [project:dataset.abc_table]
  WHERE platform IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
  GROUP BY  test 
)
ORDER BY Percentage DESC
```

Meantime, it is highly recommended to [migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) - below is how you can make it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT test, 
  COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY test) AS Total,
  ROUND(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY test) / COUNT(1) OVER(), 2) AS Percentage
FROM `project.dataset.abc_table`
WHERE platform IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
ORDER BY Percentage DESC
```

Comment: @shivi-bhatia - please consider also voting up the answer - this is equally important on SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like:

```
SELECT *, purchases/total as percent
FROM (
    SELECT *, MAX(purchases) OVER(PARTITION BY test) total
    FROM t
    )
order by percent desc
```